# Exiting program with uncaught exception when try to move from fragment to other fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I try to open other Fragment from Fragment with code:

```
btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        register();
    }
});

private void register(){
    ....
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginFragment.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Anyone have idea why my app stops working?

Runtime exception error:
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.bakalauras.rtaujenis/com.bakalauras.rtaujenis.LoginFragment}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bakalauras.rtaujenis.LoginFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

I do that becouse i found example http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example  look for TitlesFragment class in last rows else statement.

Comment: post your logcat data

Comment: A stack trace or logcat would be helpful. Also, the code you posted starts another activity, not a fragment.

Comment: My logcat didn't log only uncaught exception

Answer (score 1):

From the name of your class, which is the only thing we see since there is little to no code, it seems you are trying to load a `Fragment` using an `Intent`. This mechanism is what `Activities` use to start one another. Adding `Fragments` dynamically requires you use `FragmentTransaction` from `FragmentManager`.

If `LoginFragment` is actually an `Activity` we will need to see more code.

If `LoginFragment` is a `Fragment` please read the [Android guide for using `Fragments`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: But in Android guide tutorial they using Intent to go from ListFragment to Fragment, but when i try to do that my app stops working.

Comment: I do not think they do that. Please post the link you are referring to.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html   search for TitlesFragment class

Comment: They are not saying that. They are using an `Intent` to launch an `Activity` if they are not in dual pane mode.

Answer (score 1):

It's crashing because you are trying to start a fragment using the `startActivity` function.

That's not how fragments are used. you can think of Activity as the app's window, and the Fragments as the various sections of that app, therefore if you are trying to change from one fragment to another, you need to replace the current view using `FragmentTransaction`

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = fragmentManager1.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.container, LoginFragment);
fragmentTransaction1.commit();
```

where `R.id.container` is the frame that will contain the original view and will 'wrap' the new view.

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html) to learn how to work with fragments. Also check the official documentation Fragment to understand the life-cycle of [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) since they are different than activities

Answer (score 0):

Try this code sample.

```
private void register(){
        // Create new fragment and transaction
        Fragment newFragment = new LoginFragment(); 

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack

        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit(); 
    }
```

Comment: when i press button my fragment don't change to newFragment with your code